# In the function the for loop misses one item on the list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function that needs the find the straight numbers in list like 0, 1, 2, 3 (they need to be at least 3 or max 5)(and they need to be in the same number group which has 13 numbers in it like 0-12 13-25 etc.)In the function when it finds a straight number group and writes it on a different list it pasts the next number that needs to see.(Found straight number groups needs to be separated with "-1")

Input example: 0 1 2 14 15 16

Expected Output: 0, 1, 2, -1, 14, 15, 16, -1

Output: 0, 1, 2, -1

I tested out and if I give one more number to be in the second found straight number groups it works but it still passes the next number found after the first group.
Here is the used functions.

```
def straightNumber(array):
    backu = array[:]
    answer = []
    result = 0
    for item in backu:
        preRes = 1
        for n in range(1, 5):
            if item + n in backu and color_finder(item) == color_finder(item + n):
                preRes += 1
        if preRes > 2:
            for n in range(0, preRes + 1):
                if item + n in backu:
                    answer.append(item + n)
                    backu.remove(item + n)
            result += 1
            answer.append(-1)
    return result, backu, answer


def color_finder(item):
    if 0 <= item <= 12:
        return "y"
    elif 13 <= item <= 25:
        return "b"
    elif 26 <= item <= 38:
        return "r"
    elif 39 <= item <= 51:
        return "bl"
```

Note: The color_finder function is to help which number group of 13 is the given number in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some debugging and found out that the problem is with the index of the first for loop "for item in backu:", you start the list with 0, that was the first item of your list but then deleted 0, 1 and 2 so when it went back to the for loop, it saw that the first item of your list was 14 so went for the second item of your list: 15
[execution example with the code below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gz8Kw.png)

```
    def straightNumber(array):
        backu = array[:]
        print(backu)
        answer = []
        result = 0
        for item in backu:
            preRes = 1
            print(item)
            print(backu)
            for n in range(1, 5):
                if item + n in backu and color_finder(item) == color_finder(item + n):
                    preRes += 1
            print(preRes)
            if preRes > 2:
                for n in range(0, preRes + 1):
                    if item + n in backu:
                        answer.append(item + n)
                        backu.remove(item + n)
                result += 1
                answer.append(-1)
                print(backu)
        return result, backu, answer
```

Comment: That makes sense But I need to remove those items from the list because I can’t have the function read a number which is already used, do you know how can I fix this without changing the code so much?

Comment: One way to solve it could be adding an if statement before the backu.remove(item+n)
if item + n + 1 in backu:
     backu.remove(item+n)

Comment: I fixed the issue with adding a specific character to the first index in the backu list, now it works fine thanks for the help, you really helped me a lot with the debugging.